# How would I add an "active" class to the rendered images based on object properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following JSON file - https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.14.1/data/en_US/runesReforged.json

As you can see, there are 5 main rune categories and each category has 4 slots which contain 3 runes each ( except the first one which contains 4 runes ). My code below iterates over the 4 slots and render the images of all runes per slot. My end result looks like this:

[image]

All good so far, except that I want to to add an active class to the runes that are selected by the user. All selected runes can be found as properties inside a data property called `match`.

```
data(){
    return {
        match: null
    }
},
methods: {
    primaryPerks(){
        let perksTree = Object.entries(this.$store.state.summonerRunes).find(([key,value]) => value.id === this.match.mainParticipant.stats.perkPrimaryStyle);

        return perksTree[1]
    }
}
```

It's null because the object is assigned after a GET request. In that object there are properties called perk0, perk1, perk2 and perk3 which are the ids of the runes. I have to somehow insert a check in my iteration that renders the images and add an "active" class to the rune images if their id is equal to any of the perk properties. The problem is that I'm not sure how to implement that check.

```
<div class="runes">
    <div v-for='runes in this.primaryPerks().slots' class="perks">
        <div v-for='rune in runes.runes' class="perk">
            <img class='inactive' :src="'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/' + rune.icon" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So at some point `match` object looks something like this?

```
data(){
    return {
        match: {
           perk0: 8112,
           perk1: 8113,
           perk2: 8115,
           perk3: 8122,
        }
    }
},
```

If so, than this is how to conditionaly attach a class.

```
<div class="runes">
    <div v-for='runes in this.primaryPerks().slots' class="perks">
        <div v-for='(rune,index) in runes.runes' class="perk">
            <img :class="{inactive: Object.values(match).find(rune.id)}" :src="'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/' + rune.icon" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest you make the method for rune checking which returns true or false and takes `id` as an argument.

```
checkRune(id) {
    return Object.values(match).find(id)
}
```

then your class should look like `:class="{inactive: checkRune(rune.id)}`

Comment: No the perks contain the ID of the rune, so the class should be applied if rune.id in the loop is equal to either perk0, perk1, perk2 or perk3. Something like if (rune.id == perk0 || rune.id == perk1 || rune.id ==perk2 || rune.id == perk3) { render the image with active class }